not able to crate download button to donload pdf in the Next js using external api
I'm trying to create a download button in a Next.js application, but I'm encountering a CORS error when attempting to fetch the download URL from an external server. The error message I'm getting is:
Access to fetch at 'https://example.com/api/download/CCD' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Below is the implementation of the code:
// components/Brochure.js
"use client";
import { useState } from "react";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { useParams } from "next/navigation";

interface BrochureProps {
  data: string;
  filename?: string;
}

const Brochure: React.FC<BrochureProps> = ({
  data,
  filename = "brochure.pdf",
}) => {
  const [isDownloading, setIsDownloading] = useState(false);
  const params = useParams();

  const handleClick = async () => {
    setIsDownloading(true);
    console.log(params.slug);
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        `https://example.com/api/download/${params.slug}`
        // { mode: "no-cors" }
      );
      const blob = await response.json();
      console.log("response.data", blob);
      const downloadLink = await window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([blob]));
      const aTag = await document.createElement("a");
      aTag.href = await downloadLink;
      aTag.setAttribute("download", "brochair.pdf");
      // downloadLink.download = filename;
      document.body.appendChild(aTag);
      aTag.click();
      aTag.remove();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Download failed:", error);
    } finally {
      setIsDownloading(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="bg-[#259FAF]">
      {/* <a href={data} target="_blank"> */}
      <Button
        onClick={handleClick}
        className="text-center text-white w-full h-16 font-sans text-2xl">
        {isDownloading ? "Downloading" : "DOWNLOAD BROCHURE"}
      </Button>
      {/* </a> */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Brochure;

I'm feeling a bit lost with what to do next. Can you please guide me through this situation?

A CORS error indicates that the server is specifically blocking requests that do not come from its specified domains. It's basically a security feature. If you have access to the server you would have to change it's configuration to allow requests from your domain or disable CORS entirely.

if your chrome supports add on extensions and wanted to test locally., you can enable CORS Extension in your chrome which unblocks your development.
if you wanted it to be running on production., at your gateway., add annotations to allow CORS requests.. this can be done by your OPS engineer
